# Setting up HProf for Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, nhprof

How do I setup [NhProf](http://nhprof.com/) for Hibernate?

Comment: NhProf is for NHibernate - the .NET cousin of Java's Hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you don't setup NhProf. You setup [Hibernate profiler](http://hibernateprofiler.com/).

And [this is the how-to setup doc](http://hibernateprofiler.com/learn/usage/manual-config).